# Merge .htaccess rules?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two URL shortening scripts I want to run on the same domain, everything is ok until it comes to the .htacess which makes them work, I can only have one rewrite rule at a time, i'm sure someone with more knowledge will know how to merge these so they both work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ show.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and the second one...

```
# BEGIN YOURLS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourls-loader.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END YOURLS
```

Comment: Which one do you want to take effect? Either `show.php` or `yourls-loader.php` is going to handle all requests that don't match an existing file or directory.

Comment: Is there any difference between the URLs that should be routed to `show.php` vs the URLs that should be routed to `yourls-loader.php`?

Comment: Yes there is - they are two different short URL scripts - judging by the first comment, im assuming its impossible to run them both in the same directory...

Ive add the new one which what i'll use from now on, but I need to keep the old links alive still.

Comment: @JonLin there is one difference actually - the new URLs will be a certain amount of characters (6) the old urls are all 2,3 or 4 characters long more or less - if that works to split them up?

Answer (score 0):

> there is one difference actually - the new URLs will be a certain amount of characters (6) the old urls are all 2,3 or 4 characters long more or less -

You could try:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# for IDs that are exactly 6 characters:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteRule ^(.{6})$ show.php?id=$1 [L]

# for IDs that are 2,3 or 4
# BEGIN YOURLS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.{2,4})$ /yourls-loader.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END YOURLS
```

The key here is using the `{#}` instead of the `*`. `{6}` means exactly 6 and `{2,4}` means between 2 and 4 (inclusive).

---

If you can guarantee some sort of uniq prefix then the rules would look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ABC(.{6})$ show.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^(?!ABC)(.*)$ /yourls-loader.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi Jon,

Just thinking it may well have some that are 6 in the original. What if I make sure all URLs on the new one have some kind of unique identifier like three letters for example ABC would I then go for...so a URL might be http://url.com/abc73822

RewriteRule ^(.{ABC})$ show.php?id=$1 [L]

Comment: @user2792910 as long as it will *never* appear in the second shortened ID, see edit above

Comment: Just to confirm does that mean - any urls with ABC (can I remove the 6 characters now, back to .* ?) and the second one is excluding ABC?

Is ABC case sensitive?

Comment: @user2792910 you can remove the `{6}` and use `*`, it just means the first rule must start with `ABC` and the second rule it must **not** start with `ABC`, it is case sensitive unless you add a `NC` flag in the square brackets (no case).

Comment: Excllent, thank you so much - so would that be [L,NC] in brackets? or [LNC]?

Comment: @user2792910 `[L,NC]` need the comma.

Comment: Hmm, ok so it matches the rule and sees the URL and redirects properly, however the show.php one gives me a "Error : invalid hash" which is the same error it gives when you dont include the .htaccess at all - might be it be one of the other rules clashing?

Comment: I currently have it as

`Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteRule ^lnk(.*)$ show.php?id=$1 [L]

# BEGIN YOURLS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!lnk)(.*)$ /yourls-loader.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END YOURLS`

Comment: If I use the original all inclusive rule it works fine, if I look at the content in show.php its this, so perhaps I need to update something to match the new .htaccess rule 

`<?php
 if($_GET['id']){
  $id = addslashes($_GET['id']);
  if(file_exists("urls/$id"))
  { 
   $url = file_get_contents("urls/$id");
   header("location:".$url); 
  } else {
   echo "Error : invalid hash";
  }
 } else {
  echo "Error : no hash";
 }
?>`

Comment: Jon do you know anymore? It seems the error happens because the php is looking for the ID and not getting it. I'm not sure how to fix/change this or why its happening when the URL is being redirected properly.